# CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "totalsales" (type string) at path "_id" for model "Order" - getting this error while using aggregate fn

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregate

getting error : CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "totalsales" (type string) at path "_id" for model "Order". I was following the same code as in a tutorial but getting this error.Got the similiar error when _id didn't match objectId type. but here I am passing null which is same as in the mongose docs.

```
router.get("/get/totalsales", async (req, res) => {
  const totalSales = await Order.aggregate([
    {
      $group: {
        _id: null,
        totalsales: { $sum: "$totalPrice" },
      },
    },
  ]);
  // console.log(totalSales);
});
```

Here is the schema and model used.

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const orderSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  orderItems: [
    {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "OrderItem",
      required: true,
    },
  ],
  shippingAddress1: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  shippingAddress2: {
    type: String,
  },
  city: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  zip: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  country: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  phone: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  status: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    default: "Pending",
  },
  totalPrice: {
    type: Number,
  },
  user: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "User",
  },
  dateOrdered: {
    type: String,
    default: Date.now,
  },
});

orderSchema.virtual("id").get(function () {
  return this._id.toHexString();
});

orderSchema.set("toJSON", { virtuals: true });

exports.Order = mongoose.model("Order", orderSchema);
```

Comment: The code is working. when I copied the same code and run again.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to provide more code, I tested the code you sent and it worked:

```
const express = require('express');
const { Order } = require('./Order');

const router = express();
router.listen(3000);

new Order({
    totalPrice: 100,
    phone: 'a',
    country: 'a',
    zip: 'a',
    city: 'a',
    shippingAddress1: 'a',
}).save();

new Order({
    totalPrice: 150,
    phone: 'a',
    country: 'a',
    zip: 'a',
    city: 'a',
    shippingAddress1: 'a',
}).save();

router.get('/get/totalsales', async (req, res) => {
    const totalSales = await Order.aggregate([
        {
            $group: {
                _id: null,
                totalsales: { $sum: '$totalPrice' },
            },
        },
    ]);
    res.write(totalSales[0].totalsales.toString());
    res.end();
});
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. The code worked after I copied the same code and run again. I don't know why it didn't work previously cause I tried compiling the code multiple times. And also had similiar experience with some other libraries like express-jwt where some functionalities doesn't work and it also worked after sometime without making any changes to the code.